# GetX: how to access previousley updated value not on widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have 2 screens: **ShowProductDetail** and **EditProductDetail**.

The Product model

```
class Product {
  String? id;
  String? name;
  String? description;
  double? price;
  double? discount;
  int? originalStockCount;
  int? currentStockCount;
}
```

And the controller

```
class ProductController extends GetxController {
    var currentProduct = Product().obs
    
    // aditional methods to update, delete etc
}
```

First I see the product detail **on ShowProductDetail**, then click the edit button to display **EditProductDetail**. Do some editings, and the go back to **ShowProductDetail**

Thanks to Obx, all widgets displaying the product detail with automatically updated accordingly, e.g.

```
Obx(() => Text(controller.currentProduct.value.description!,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.purple))
```

But what if I want to access the recently updated values not on widget?

e.g

```
if (product.currentStockCount <= 10){
    // show alert "Stock is reaching 0"
}
```

Assume `product.currentStockCount` on **EditProductDetail** is updated from 30 to 8.
When I go back to **ShowProductDetail**, that part will not be executed, because `product.currentStockCount` still refers to its old value, which is 30.

How to fix this?

Comment: How are you updating `currentStockCount` and how are you navigating back to `ShowProductDetail`? It should reflect the new value when you go back but I'd need to see what you're doing to see what the problem is.

Comment: On *EditProductDetail*, an update API is called (not shown), which if success then returns the whole JSON of the updated product, like this: `Product updatedProduct = Product.fromJSON(....); controller.product.value = updatedProduct; controller.product.refresh()` (assume I update all the details, not just current stock count). Then I go back to `ShowProductDetail`, and thanks to `Obx`, the product name description, price etc displayed on `Text` are automatically updated. No problem here. The issue is doing something not related to widget, e.g the if block shown above.

Comment: Well without actually seeing your code I can suggest if you're using `Get.back()` to navigate there directly with `Get.to(()=> ShowProductDetail ())` or `Get.toNamed(...)`. I just did a quick conditional check on an updated value on a previous page and it was only executed when I navigated with `Get.toNamed`